# field extensions - prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

[ This is question that appears as an excercise in Ian Stewart's book Galois Theory (4th edition). ]

I think the way to go about it is as follows, would appreciate someone's input on whether I got this right:

Write $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$

We'll prove that for $L' = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7})$, it holds that both $L \subseteq L'$ as well as $L' \subseteq L$, hence $L = L'$.

The direction $L' \subseteq L$ holds trivially.

For the other direction we have the following (using basic closure properties of fields and the binomial formula for n=3):

$(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7})^3 = 5\sqrt{5} + 3\cdot5\sqrt{7} + 3\cdot7\sqrt{5} + 7\sqrt{7} = 26\sqrt{5} + 22\sqrt{7} \in L'$

hence

$(26\sqrt{5} + 22\sqrt{7}) - 22\cdot(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}) \in L' \implies 4\sqrt{5} \in L' \implies \sqrt{5} \in L'$

Therefore, again by basic field properties, $(\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}) - \sqrt{5} = \sqrt{7} \in L'$

QED

Is this kosher? I'm still not very comfortable with field extensions, any input appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the conventional way of doing this, and it seems to work, so it is probably right

Comment: Yeah! That's a nice proof.

Comment: Also, this is a quadratic extension, and I think there is a formula somewhere that says any quadratic extension is a simple extension

Comment: Looks ok to me. A possibly more common way of going about it is to observe that
$$\frac2{\sqrt 7+\sqrt5}=\frac{2(\sqrt7-\sqrt5)}{(\sqrt7-\sqrt5)(\sqrt7+\sqrt5)}=\frac{2(\sqrt{7}-\sqrt5)}{2}=\sqrt7-\sqrt5$$ is an element of $L'$ and go from there. After all, $L'$ must also be closed under division (or taking reciprocals).

Comment: @Seth $[L':\Bbb{Q}]=4$ so this is not a quadratic extension.